# Group icons for running instances of program on top of button in taskbar in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

On my new work laptop, when I start a program from the taskbar, the icon running instance is placed to the far right of current icons in taskbar. Maybe I'm suffering from Mandela Effect, but I could swear on previous laptops, the icon(s) would be grouped on top of the main button.   This is annoying because I'll go to maximize a program I have running and I'll start a new version on accident.  Is there a setting somewhere I'm missing.

Note, I've already checked the "Combine taskbar buttons" setting in Taskbar settings.  It is set to "Always, hide labels"

Answer (score 1):

Try unpinning (if you have pinned) the main program from the taskbar, and pinning one of the running instances, then see if further instances are all grouped together now.  Whether this works or not depends on the program, so your mileage may vary.

Comment: I gave that a shot just now, but pinning one of the running instances is not an option when I right-click on it in the task bar

Comment: @Kevin You unpinned the other icon first?  I just had to do this same thing on my new work laptop this morning, where Microsoft Edge comes with Windows 10, but they had it set up to use with one work account when I wanted to use it with another work account.  When I created a new Edge user profile for the account I wanted to use it with, it opened Edge in a window to the far right of all pinned icons, which is what I've experienced before.  I unpinned the previously default pinned Edge icon, then was able to pin the one I already have open, and move it where I like.  Good luck!